# gnuplot filling color between upper and lower bound

Tags: gnuplot

I have three columns data.txt file. I would like to fill the area with color between upper and lower bound. How can I do that? My data.txt file goes as follows,

```
#Time   Force   SD
0.000   42.155  1.974
4.890   48.548  3.773
16.102  53.244  4.959
24.215  58.864  5.677
37.698  72.483  4.828
69.354  78.334  3.557
85.586  83.071  7.040
101.155 84.780  5.411
```

plot "data.txt" u 1:($2+$3) and u 1:($2-$3) w filledcurve (Is there any thing like this?)

Many thanks!

Comment: I realized I could make two plots with filledcurve option, one with the "desired" color and the other with the background color. But wondering if there is even a better option. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use three columns in the `using` statement (see also `help filledcurves`):

```
plot 'data.txt' using 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves
```

[image]

Comment: @Christoph How would I be able to achieve a similar type graph by using [2 CSV files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063403/how-to-draw-a-filledcurve-graph-with-gnuplot-by-using-2-csv-files)?