# How to draw a filledcurve graph with GNUPlot by using 2 csv files

Tags: gnuplot

If I have 2 csv files ("CSV1.csv" `dataname_1` and "CSV2.csv" `dataname_2`), how can I draw filled curve graph from the data of 2 csv files. The formats of these CSV files are identical, where 2 is timestamps and 5 is the value thus the `using 2:5`

I am trying this:

```
plot dataname_2 using 2:5 title "Above" with filledcurves above lc rgb 'blue',\
     dataname_1 using 2:5 title "Below" with filledcurves below lc rgb 'red',\
     dataname_2 using 2:5 title "Engine Starts" with lines lc rgb "#1E90FF",\
     dataname_1 using 2:5 title "Engine Hours" with lines lc rgb "#FF1493"
```

I need to modify the code above so that the output is:

[image]

Comment: you would first have to merge the two .csv files, as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549004/gnuplot-plot-data-from-two-files-in-one-x-coordinate-in-other-y

Comment: @SébastienGuarnay I have 2 independent files which both have an independently corresponding X with a Y value. However the X-axis is timestamp in both files. The site linked in your comment, has 2 files where one only has an X value and other has a (corresponding) Y value.

Comment: yes indeed. So in your case, you would plot the second graph using the right columns instead of `2:5`, for example `2:10` if there are 5 columns per file and the timestamps are the same. You might then fill the curves, and then perhaps use inferiority conditions such as `using 2:($5<$10 ? $5 : $10)` to fill the part under the 2 curves with white, in an extra graph.

Comment: and if the timestamps are not the same, you would first have to re-sample the data to make them the same.

Answer (score 2):

A solution which will probably always work is to prepare the data with whatever external tool in such a way that gnuplot can handle and plot it. I'm aware that the philosophy of gnuplot is to concentrate on plotting and not necessarily on data preparation for plotting. However, it is always good to have a minimum set of features to do some basic data preparation.

In your case you have several problems, well, let's call it challenges ;-)

- `with filledcurves` requires data within the same file or datablock
- however, gnuplot cannot easily merge datafiles line by line (it can with some workaround, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61559658/7295599). Simply appending would be no problem with gnuplot.
- the latter doesn't help you since `with filledcurves` needs identical `x` for upper and lower curve, i.e. `x,y1,y2` and your data has `x1,y1` and `x2,y2`
- however, gnuplot cannot easily resample data (it can with some workaround, see:  [Resampling data with gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54362441/7295599))
- `with filledcurves` cannot directly fill curves with non-monotonic increasing x (not the case with your data. Here just for illustration purposes) (it can with some workaround see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53769446/7295599 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/56176717/7295599)

So a workaround for all this could be the following (works with gnuplot 5.2, maybe can be tweaked to work with earlier versions):

**Assumptions:**

1. Data `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` in two files or datablocks
2. Data has not necessarily identical `x`, i.e. `x1,y1` and `x2,y2`
3. Data may contain non-monotonic `x`
4. the two curves have only *one* intersection (well, the workaround below will just take the first one)

**Procedure:**

1. if not already, get the data into a datablock.
2. Find the intersection of the curves.
3. Create new datablocks: `Filled1` using Data1 from the beginning to the intersection point and using Data2 backwards from the intersection point to the beginning. `Filled2` using Data1 from the end backwards to the intersection point and using Data2 from the intersection point to the end.
4. Plot `$Data1` and `$Data2` `with lines` and `$Filled1` and `$Filled2` `with filledcurves`

Steps 2 and 3, probably will not be much shorter in another programming language unless there are dedicated functions.

Get files to datablock: (see also here [gnuplot: load datafile 1:1 into datablock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54600172/7295599))

```
# get files to datablocks
set table $Data1
    plot 'myFile1.dat' u 1:2 w table
set table $Data2
    plot 'myFile2.dat' u 1:2 w table
unset table`
```

**Code:** (copy&paste for gnuplot >=5.2)

```
### fill intersecting curves from two files not having identical x
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
1   1
2   0
4   1
3   3
5   5
6   6
8   8
9   9
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
1    3
3.5  5
7.5  1
9    7
EOD

# orientation of 3 points a,b,c: -1=clockwise, +1=counterclockwise
Orientation(a,b,c) = sgn((word(b,1)-word(a,1))*(word(c,2)-word(a,2)) - \
                         (word(c,1)-word(a,1))*(word(b,2)-word(a,2)))

# check for intersection of segment a-b with segment c-d,
# 0=no intersection, 1=intersection
IntersectionCheck(a,b,c,d) = \
    Orientation(a,c,b) == Orientation(a,d,b) || \
    Orientation(c,a,d) == Orientation(c,b,d) ? 0 : 1

# coordinate of intersection
M(a,b) = real(word(a,1)*word(b,2) - word(a,2)*word(b,1))

N(a,b,c,d) = (word(a,1)-word(b,1))*(word(c,2)-word(d,2)) - \
             (word(a,2)-word(b,2))*(word(c,1)-word(d,1))

Px(a,b,c,d) = (M(a,b)*(word(c,1)-word(d,1)) - (word(a,1)-word(b,1))*M(c,d))/N(a,b,c,d)
Py(a,b,c,d) = (M(a,b)*(word(c,2)-word(d,2)) - (word(a,2)-word(b,2))*M(c,d))/N(a,b,c,d)

Intersection(a,b,c,d) = sprintf("%g %g", Px(a,b,c,d), Py(a,b,c,d))

stop = 0
do for [i=1:|$Data1|-1] {
    a = $Data1[i]
    b = $Data1[i+1]
    do for [j=1:|$Data2|-1] {
        c = $Data2[j]
        d = $Data2[j+1]
        if (IntersectionCheck(a,b,c,d)) { 
        i0 = i; j0 = j
        stop=1; break }
    }
    if (stop) { break }
}

# create the datablocks for the outline to be filled
set print $Filled1
    do for [k=1:i0] { print $Data1[k] }
    print Intersection(a,b,c,d)
    do for [k=j0:1:-1] { print $Data2[k] }
set print $Filled2
    do for [k=|$Data1|:i0+1:-1] { print $Data1[k] }
    print Intersection(a,b,c,d)
    do for [k=j0+1:|$Data2|] { print $Data2[k] }
set print

set key top left
plot $Filled1 u 1:2 w filledcurves lc rgb 0x3f48cc, \
     $Filled2 u 1:2 w filledcurves lc rgb 0xed1c24, \
     $Data1 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lw 5 lc rgb 0x99d9ea, \
     $Data2 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lw 5 lc rgb 0xff80c0
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]