# Gnuplot plotting using column data from multiple files

Tags: file, gnuplot

I have two files "f.txt" and "g.txt". The data in both files are arranged in two columns, the column separator being just a few whitespaces.
The first column stand for the independent variable "x" and the second column for f(x) (or g(x)).
It is easy to plot the function y= f(x) and y = g(x), but is there a simple way to plot f(x) against g(x)? Of course, using bash, I could create an "intermediary" file with first column g(x) and second column f(x) and then plotting normally this file. Is there however a way to do this without actually creating this file?

Comment: You can combine the files and feed the result directly to gnuplot without creating an intermediate file https://stackoverflow.com/a/20070138/2604213

Answer (score 1):

Your question was partly contradictory. It looked like you have two files with two columns each, i.e. `x,f(x)` and `x,g(x)`. I assume that the number of rows and the values of x are identical. And you "simply" want to plot `f(x)` versus `g(x)`. But this is *not* the same as plotting `f(g(x))` (as in your original question). In the latter case you probably would need interpolation.

@Christoph already pointed to a simple solution merging to files with awk.
In case you don't have or don't want to use awk, here is a somewhat cumbersome *gnuplot-only* solution.

1. load files 1:1 to datablock (see [gnuplot: load datafile 1:1 into datablock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54600172/7295599), although, still not fully answered)
2. remove the end of line character(s). This depends on the operating system. For Windows I have to put `\r` as end of line character (for some reason not `\r\n`). Currently, I cannot test Linux and MacOS.
3. print/append lines to a new datablock

**Data:**

`f.txt`

```
A,B
1,3
2,6
3,5
```

`g.txt`

```
A,C
1,8
2,4
3,7
```

**Code:**

```
### merge two files (merging their lines)
# assumption: equal number of lines in each file
reset session

# load files 1:1 to datablocks
FILE1 = 'f.txt'
if (GPVAL_SYSNAME[:7] eq "Windows") { load '< echo   $Data1 ^<^<EOD  & type "'.FILE1.'"' }
else                                { load '< echo "\$Data1  << EOD" &  cat "'.FILE1.'"' } # Linux & MacOS
FILE2 = 'g.txt'
if (GPVAL_SYSNAME[:7] eq "Windows") { load '< echo   $Data2 ^<^<EOD  & type "'.FILE2.'"' }
else                                { load '< echo "\$Data2  << EOD" &  cat "'.FILE2.'"' } # Linux & MacOS

mySeparator = ","
myEOLc = sprintf("\r",0)     # End of Line character Linux: "\n", Windows: "\r\n", Mac: "\r"
# function for removing EOL character(s) from a string
RemoveEOLc(s) = s[strlen(s)-strlen(myEOLc)+1:strlen(s)] eq myEOLc ?  s[1:strlen(s)-strlen(myEOLc)] : s

set print $Data3
    do for [i=1:|$Data1|] {
        print sprintf("%s%s%s", RemoveEOLc($Data1[i]), mySeparator, RemoveEOLc($Data2[i]))
    }
set print

print $Data3
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
A,B,A,C
1,3,1,8
2,6,2,4
3,5,3,7
```

An then plot your data as you like...

**Addition:**

If your files have whitespace as column separator you can use `word("string",n)` to extract a "column" from `$Data[i]` (see `help word`).
Then you need to change the lines:

```
mySeparator = " "
```

and

```
print sprintf("%s%s%s", word(RemoveEOLc($Data1[i]),2), mySeparator, word(RemoveEOLc($Data2[i]),2))
```

**Result:**

```
B C
3 8
6 4
5 7
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was indeed not precise in what I wanted, but you correctly understood my question. 
Sorry for being very picky, but would it be possible for the result to only have the rows B and C, i.e. without the (duplicate) rows A?

Comment: only B and C would also be possible, but a bit more cumbersome in gnuplot. What is your column separator? Whitespace would be easier than other characters like `,` or `;` etc...

Comment: You may assume that my column separator are (a couple of) whitespaces.